# In Emacs, how to auto complete built-in function names like erase-buffer?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, editor

I'm playing with *elisp* and I want to know if there is a way for me to auto-complete Emacs built-in function names like `erase-buffer`. I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to auto-complete strings and I want to know if there is a similar feature for built-in function names.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get completion working for Emacs lisp. My favourite is to install [`company-mode`](http://company-mode.github.io/):

> Company is a text completion framework for Emacs. The name stands for "complete anything". It uses pluggable back-ends and front-ends to retrieve and display completion candidates.

Simply installing it from GNU ELPA and enabling it with something like

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-company-mode)
```

will give you completion for Emacs lisp and a few other languages. With a little more configuration and a couple of plugins, I've found `company-mode` to be an excellent completion tool for many other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

By default you can use `M-TAB` (aka `ESC TAB` if your desktop environment catches `M-TAB` before Emacs gets to see it).  But I use

```
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

after which TAB should perform completion when possible (and yes, elisp-mode provides completion for function names and variable names, along with a few more cases).